# 403 forbidden error when accessing one website only via my home wifi. How to fix?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403

Only get the error when trying to visit the site via my home BT wifi, any browser. Have tried restarting the router, disabling cache in inspect element and clearing all cookies and caches in Chrome and Safari settings. Can access the website via 3g/4g and from my office and friends computers.

Please help as I need to make some updates in Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Go to your wordpress folder and delete .htaccess file. That is problem usually.

Comment: Delete the .htaccess file? There are redirects in there. Also won't that open up security vulnerabilities?

Comment: Then you can add underscore "_" or something like that. WP will generate a new .htaccess file, then copy and paste things from old to a new file. That shout work.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try.

Comment: P.S when you delete .htaccess file wordpress generates new one.